# How to manage state transitions in INET

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to implement data acknowledgement in x-mac protocol. The algorithm is, after the packet transmission is over, the sending node will wait for an acknowledgement from the receiver. For that I added a new state WAIT_ACK. But during runtime, I can see the node cannot make state transition from `WAIT_TX_DATA_OVER` to `WAIT_ACK`. I am getting the following error.

> <!> Undefined event of type 204 in state 7 (Radio state 2)! -- in module (inet::XMac1) SensorNetworkShowcaseA.sensor3.wlan[0].mac (id=181), at t=0.10677288732s, event #62

Note: `XMAC1_DATA_TX_OVER` = 204 and state 7 is `WAIT_ACK`

```
case SEND_DATA:

    if (msg->getKind() == XMAC1_STOP_PREAMBLES) {
        sendDataPacket();
        macState = WAIT_TX_DATA_OVER;
        return;
    }
    else if (msg->getKind() == XMAC1_SWITCHING_FINISHED) {
        sendDataPacket();
        macState = WAIT_TX_DATA_OVER;
        return;
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
    break;

case WAIT_TX_DATA_OVER:
     if (msg->getKind() == XMAC1_DATA_TX_OVER) {
        scheduleAt(simTime() + (slotDuration / 2), data_ack_timeout);
        macState = WAIT_ACK;
        radio->setRadioMode(IRadio::RADIO_MODE_RECEIVER);
        changeDisplayColor(GREEN);

    }
    break;
case WAIT_ACK:
    if (msg->getKind() == XMAC1_DATA_TX_OVER) {
        delete msg;
        return;
    }
   ...
   }
    
    break;
```

Update

In runtime, below is what I can see after the execution stops

> INFO (XMac1)SensorNetworkShowcaseA.sensor3.wlan[0].mac: node 0A-AA-00-00-00-04 : State WAIT_TX_DATA_OVER, message XMAC_DATA_TX_OVER, new state  WAIT_ACK
> INFO (ApskScalarRadio)SensorNetworkShowcaseA.sensor3.wlan[0].radio: SensorNetworkShowcaseA.sensor3.wlan[0].radio: Radio mode changed from TRANSMITTER to RECEIVER.
> INFO (ApskScalarRadio)SensorNetworkShowcaseA.sensor3.wlan[0].radio: SensorNetworkShowcaseA.sensor3.wlan[0].radio: Changing radio reception state from UNDEFINED to IDLE.
> INFO (ApskScalarRadio)SensorNetworkShowcaseA.sensor3.wlan[0].radio: SensorNetworkShowcaseA.sensor3.wlan[0].radio: Changing radio transmission state from IDLE to UNDEFINED.
> <!> Undefined event of type 204 in state 7 (Radio state 2)! -- in module (inet::XMac1) SensorNetworkShowcaseA.sensor3.wlan[0].mac (id=181), at t=0.10677288732s, event #62

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, this should not happen, so something in your assumptions are wrong. Most likely, you are NOT running this code. Make sure that this code is indeed executed (you may build a release version and run the debug version or something else). In these cases I often modify temporarily the error message in the code to see whether code changes are really compiled into the executable, just to be sure that I'm running the indeed the code I assume running.

Comment: This is the code I am running. In my question, I have added the information I can see after the execution stops with error. As you suggested, I also tried by changing the code, then I can see the affect of code changes. Would you please suggest me if my code is wrong or there are other things I need to look at to fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I see, your code is correct. The error you are seeing is thrown at the end of the function and the execution should not reach that point as the function should return from inside the switch statement. Now this is clearly not the case, so you should debug and see the actual execution path in this event. That will show you why the WAIT_ACK case block is not executed.

Comment: Debugging shows a thread in ```throw cRuntimeError("Undefined event of type %d in state %d (Radio state %d)!", msg->getKind(), macState, radio->getRadioMode());```. This is the only thing that is showing from .cc file. I cannot even understand how to find out the main problem from it. Is there any way to debug this thread more? Thank you.

Comment: Sure it shows that, because that was the line which printed the error. You should try to stop the execution with a breakpoint at the beginning of that method and step through. The interesting thing is how the execution got there. Start you simulation using Qtenv in a debugger then "Simulate/Run until..." event #62 and then choose "Simulate/Debug next event". Step into the handleMessage call and step through the code.